# Apply Changes from a delta live streaming table to another delta live streaming table

Tags: databricks, delta-live-tables

I get the below error when I try to do APPLY CHANGES from one delta live streaming table to another delta live stremaing table. Is this scenario not supported?

```
pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: rajib_db.employee_address_stream is a permanent view, which is not supported by streaming reading API such as `DataStreamReader.table` yet.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean to perform `APPLY CHANGES` to one table, and then stream from it into another table, then it's not supported yet.  Please reach someone from Databricks (solution architect or customer success engineer) to provide feedback to the Databricks product team.

Also, if you'll do the `describe extended` on the table into which you do `APPLY CHANGES` then you will see that it's not a real table, but a view over another table that filters out some entries.